# PHP - How to invoke a function when database table is inserted or deleted

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am making a experimental chat application using SSE(Server Sent Event- javascript) and i cannot get a hold on how to flush out the data when a user data is inserted into the table.

What I need to achieve is,

1. Make the php to do an Infinite loop
2. If new row of message data is inserted to a table (lets call it messages), 
    a function is invoked and the new inserted row is sent back to browser
3. Be idle until new row is inserted

Below is what I wanted to get

```
     <?php
     //creating Event stream 
     header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
     header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

      while( IF NEW ROW IS INSERTED){
         flush_data();
      }
```

and I am unable to figure out how to know in php when new row is inserted in table.

> (I use  pdo and mysql)

Comment: `1.Make the php to do an Infinite loop`: Just don't :)

Comment: What is SSE? I'm pretty sure the SSE tag you put on this question isn't the SSE you are thinking about.

Comment: I won't even work. Your browser will tell you that it ended an infite loop.

Comment: please can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not ideal language for this purpose, as it's designed for short runs. If you still want to use PHP, take a look at [PHP Web Socket server](https://github.com/Devristo/phpws) . The basic loop is in documentation, you might prefere to use socket notification instead of continualy querying the database.

Comment: `as it's designed for short runs` ? what do you mean by that its a short run server side script ?

Comment: Can you help me with how to get the newly inserted rows

Comment: @marek but in all EventSource guides out there they use php as server side right?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yes. It's getting better, but PHP has problems with leaking memory.

Comment: @SivSivSree You have to query database for new messages in the anonymous function added by `addPeriodicTimer()` method. PHP is server side, but what really runs long is web server, eg. apache.